# Проблема с односвязным списком

Tags: c++, списки, односвязный-список

Вобщем, есть вопросик. Делаю односвязный список. Естественно, это класс и структура. Вообщем видел другие, функцию добавления элемента, пишут через new Item, я же просто объявляю Item. Вроде бы по отладке все пашет, но когда вызываю функцию вывода, значения поинтеров firstItem и lastItem теряются... Может кто сможет помочь? Вроде бы при обычном объявлении должна тоже выделяться память (Item itm;)

List.h

```
#pragma once 


class List
{
    struct Item {
        int number;
        Item * next;
    };
    int countAll;
    Item * firstItem = NULL;
    Item * lastItem = NULL;
public:
    void AddLast(int);
    void RemoveLast();

    void ShowAllElements();
    void showItem(Item *);
    List();
    ~List();
};
```

list.cpp

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
#include "List.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void List::AddLast(int n)
{
    Item itm = { n, NULL };
    /*itm->next = NULL;
    itm->number = n;*/
    if (firstItem == lastItem) {
        firstItem = &itm;
        lastItem = firstItem->next;
    }
    else {
        lastItem = &itm;
        lastItem->next = itm.next;
        lastItem = lastItem->next;
    }

}

void List::RemoveLast()
{
    Item * tmp;
    tmp = lastItem->next;
    delete lastItem;
    lastItem = tmp;

}

void List::ShowAllElements()
{
    Item *next = firstItem->next;
    Item *itm = firstItem;
    while (next) {
        showItem(itm);
        itm = itm->next;
        next = itm->next;
    }
}
void List::showItem(Item * itm) {
    cout << "there is number: " << itm->number << endl;
}
List::List()
{
    Item itm;
    this->firstItem = this->lastItem = &itm;
}


List::~List()
{
}
```

main

```
// OneRootList.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "List.h"
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    List list;
    list.AddLast(1);
    list.AddLast(1);
    list.ShowAllElements();
}
```

Comment: " другие, функцию добавления элемента, пишут через new Item, я же просто объявляю Item" - это ты зря)) new - динамическое выделение памяти. Выделенная память сохраняется даже после закрытия ф-ции. Но, если вы создаете массив без использования динамического выделения памяти, то время жизни этого массива ограничено областью его видимости. Т.е. память будет освобождена сразу по завершении ф-ции.

Answer (score 3):

```
void List::AddLast(int n)
{
    // создали ЛОКАЛЬНУЮ переменную 
    Item itm = { n, NULL };
    /* ... */
        // присвоили её адрес...
        firstItem = &itm;
    // а вот тут локальня переменная itm уничтожается, и
    // firstItem теперь указывает в никуда
}
```

Та же проблема и в конструкторе. И при этом ещё и в методе `RemoveLast()` вы применяете `delete` к памяти, которая вообще непонятно что из себя представляет.

Выводы:

1. Новый элемент списка должен создаваться через `new`
2. Предусмотреть корректное удаление созданных элементов в деструкторе.